# Generalizability of a measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm confused about the generality of a result from our text book. The result reads:

> Let $(\mathcal{X},\Bbb{E}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $f$ be non-negative and $\Bbb{E}-\Bbb{B}$-measurable from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\Bbb{R}$ (written as $f\in \mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{X}, \Bbb{E}) $). The set function $\nu : \Bbb{E} \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ defined by 
>   $$\nu(A)= \int_A f \;d\mu, \;\;\; \text{with}  \; A\in\Bbb{E} $$
>
> is a measure on $(\mathcal{X}, \Bbb{E})$

How general is this? Does this hold e.g., if $\mathcal{X}=\Bbb{R} \otimes \Bbb{R}$, $\Bbb{E}=\Bbb{B}\otimes \Bbb{B}$ and $\mu=m \otimes m$, where m is the Lebesgue measure. Or for even higher dimensions?

Comment: This is very general, and applies to any measure space, including $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: What happens when you try to do the proof in your more general situations?

Comment: @GEdgar I would try to show $\nu(\emptyset)=0$, which is trivial for $n$ dimensions, however, I'm less sure about $\sigma - additivity$. This is really the core of my confusion.

Comment: @Berci Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you familiar with the monotone convergence theorem for integrals on general measure spaces?

Comment: Hmmm, why would it not hold in these situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{A_i\}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\mathbb E$ then
$$
\nu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = \int_{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i} f\ \mathsf d\mu = \int_{\mathcal X} f\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathsf 1_{A_i}\ \mathsf d\mu.
$$
Let $f_n = f\sum_{i=1}^n \mathsf 1_{A_i}$. Then $f_n(x)\geqslant 0$ and $f_n(x)\leqslant f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x\in\mathcal X$, so by the monotone convergence theorem we have
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathcal X} f\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathsf 1_{A_i}\ \mathsf d\mu &= \int_{\mathcal X} \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\ \mathsf d\mu\\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathcal X} f_n\ \mathsf d\mu\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i} f\ \mathsf d\mu\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \nu(A_i)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \nu(A_i).
\end{align}
It follows that $\nu$ is a measure on $(\mathcal X,\mathbb E)$.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks! I hadn't thought to use MCT, but it's obvious that it does the trick.

Comment: @Math1000   In this setting, how one can show  $\nu({{\mathcal{X}}})=1$ given that $\int_{{\mathcal{X}}} f d\mu=1$

Comment: @ADAM If $\int_X f\ \mathsf du=1$, then by monotonicity of measures, $\int_Ef\  d\mu \leqslant 1$ for all measurable sets $E$. Assuming that $f$ and $\mu$ are non-negative, the result follows.